# What does `free_raw_data` do in `lightgbm.Dataset()`?

Tags: python, lightgbm

I've read the [docs](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Dataset.html#lightgbm.Dataset) and an explanation on the [FAQ](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FAQ.html#error-messages-cannot-before-construct-dataset). But the former is just a tautology and the latter explains things with `self.` as if I would be regularly using `Dataset` in my own classes. Usually, I load up a dataset and use it to train my models, so never need to use `self.` anywhere. I am a beginner though.

Where does the data 'go' if it is free? What happens when it is not free? Why would I want my data to be free or not? Is this something I, as an ML Engineer, would use, or is it (as the FAQ seems to indicate) more for the LGBM devs and the inner workings of the class?

Comment: When talking about memory and variables, _free_ means _delete_.

Comment: Oooooh. So it deletes the raw data and just leaves you with the lightgbm.Dataset object to save memory?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the comments into an answer.

When talking about memory and variables, *free* means *delete*. So, it deletes the raw data which leaves just the `lightgbm.Dataset` object in memory.